# Getting route using nameof for action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the absolute route of an action, for example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    return View();
  }

}
```

So I tried the following options:

```
var r1 = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Scheme);

var r2 = urlHelper.RouteUrl(nameof(HomeController.Index), null, Request.Scheme);
```

I get the correct absolute route in **r1** but **r2** is null. Why?

Can't I use the nameof in RouteUrl as the name of the Route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx), but rather the fact that you're calling two different functions here. The `nameof` operator given the `HomeController.Index` as an argument is equivalent to the string `"Index"`.

*For example:*

```
var r1 = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Scheme);
var r2 = urlHelper.RouteUrl("Index", null, Request.Scheme);
```

*Is the same as this:*

```
var r1 = urlHelper.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home", null, Request.Scheme);
var r2 = urlHelper.RouteUrl(nameof(HomeController.Index), null, Request.Scheme);
```

> The `nameof` operator is used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable, type, or member

What you really need to figure out is why `urlHelper.Action` behaves differently than `urlHelper.RouteUrl`. But the issue is not `nameof`.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but shouldn't be possible to get the absolute route using nameof either in Action or RouteUrl using nameof instead of specifying the Action and Controller values. I though nameof would be used that way.

Comment: My point is that `urlHelper.RouteUrl` isn't working regardless of whether you use `nameof` or not. The issue is not `nameof`, but your expectation of the `urlHelper.RouteUrl` function.